# Undefined constant in php

Tags: php

Коллеги, добрый день, почему у меня не работает функция fa?

```
<?php
    interface A
    {
        public function fa();
        public const a = 0;
    }

    class B implements A
    {
        public function fa()
        {
            echo "a";
        }
    }

    echo B::a;
    B -> fa();
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "B" in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\ООП\Интерфейсы.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\ООП\Интерфейсы.php on line 24

Comment: Скорее всего забыли сделать `$b = new B()`. Класс создали, а экземпляр класса нет

Comment: метод не статический, а вызван как статический (точнее как-то гибридно :D ).... не статические методы надо вызывать от экземпляра класса

Comment: Да, что то я совсем забыл... Спасибо всем)